# "Networks must maintain data on 'its' users..." Grammatical mistake by BBC News?

Tags: grammar

Has BBC News made a mistake in this [article](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-28583669)?

> It includes measures to ensure that bloggers cannot remain anonymous, and states that social **networks** must maintain six months of data on **its** users.

**Networks** is plural, so instead of **its** it should be **their**.

Comment: Seems like a mistake.

Comment: I also doubt this - ***on*** its users. Shouldn't it be ***of?*** You maintain data *of* user; if you maintain *data* **on** something, that **on** becomes a non-living thing such as a server or a hard drive! :) So, it is *I maintain data of users on a cloud.*

Comment: @MaulikV: The guy who wrote the article seems to be Russian. And in the Russian language the preposition "on" is used in the sense of "against." So they are keeping data against the users.

Comment: No, the *on* thing seems to be native allright. Recall the idiomatic expression *to keep tabs ON someone*. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle And it's probably a transference from pre-digital keep *records on* a subject (as opposed to *a record of* a particular fact).

Comment: No, the usage of "on" is perfectly all right. And, as @CopperKettle pointed out, _keep tabs on someone_ is a great example. Here's a reference- _"http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+tabs+on"_

Comment: I would regard *of* as denoting possession in this context. “Data ***of*** a user” is data *belonging to* that user. If I enter my résumé into a job search site in January, and I delete it in April, the site might be required to keep a backup copy until October – that’s maintaining six months of data *of* the users. But since the sentence refers to anonymity, it is probably referring to log information (journals, audit trails, metadata, etc): for example, user _X_ logged in from IP address _Y_ at time _Z_. These would be referred to as data (or information or facts) *on* or *about* the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does indeed seem like a grammar mistake.

I can only speculate that an earlier draft referred to some specific social network; "social networks" refers to multiple services, so the phrase "social networks" would need to take a plural preposition later on in the sentence.